# LoopBack version 4 Interceptor issue

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs

I am trying to call a log function which is in the document using interceptor in LoopBack 4 as illustrated below;

```
@intercept(log) // `log` is an interceptor function
export class PingController {

}
```

log function in LoopBack 4 docs

```
const log: Interceptor = async (invocationCtx, next) => {
    console.log('log: before-' + invocationCtx.methodName);
    // Wait until the interceptor/method chain returns
    const result = await next();
    console.log('log: after-' + invocationCtx.methodName);
    return result;
};
```

But I get an error;

> cannot find name Interceptor

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Interceptor } from '@loopback/context';
```

Able to get Interceptor Object from @loopback/context latest version